# Filtering fetched data array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am fetching data from firebase and trying to filter it so I can display the data differently as needed, the data is fetched correctly and arrives but I am struggling with filtering the data when it arrives, the filter is triggered before the data arrives it seems.

1. I have tried wrapping everything in a promise (code below).
2. I have tried async/await (code below)
3. Tested the filter manually with hard-coded data, so the filter is working.

Promise:

```
eventsToday() {
    let uid = this.$store.state.user.activeUser
    let today = '2034'

    const events = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let fetchedData = getCalanderList(uid)
      resolve(fetchedData)
    })

    events.then(data => {
      console.log('Recieved data:', data.data)
      // Returns Array with 5 Objects

      let filteredData = data.data.filter(item => {
        return item.dateStamp == today
      })

      console.log('Filtered Data:', filteredData)
      // Returns Empty Array
    })
```

Async / Await:

```
async eventsToday() {
  let uid = this.$store.state.user.activeUser
  let today = '2034'

  const events = await getCalanderList(uid)
  console.log('Recieved Data', events.data)
  // Returns Array with 5 Objects

  const filteredData = await events.data.filter(item => {
    return item.dateStamp == today
  })
  console.log('Filtered Data:', filteredData)
  // Returns Empty Array 
},
```

the events.data returns an array of 5 objects:
      [{
        day: 'monday',
        dateStamp: '2033'
      },
      {
        day: 'tuesday',
        dateStamp: '2034'
      },
      {
        day: 'wednesday',
        dateStamp: '2034'
      },
      {
        day: 'thursday',
        dateStamp: '2035'
      },
      {
        day: 'friday',
        dateStamp: '2035'
      }]

Comment: share value of `dateStamp` or `events.data`

Comment: Hi, you can try to add a if  condition on html attribute where you have applied filter. For example:  <li ng-if="filteredData" ng-repeat="data in filteredData| yourFilter">

Comment: if `await getCalanderList(uid)` works then first snippet is wrong. and if `events ` is an array then doing `events.data` is wrong so share your events object data or metadata for it.

Comment: Just added the object, I managed to solve the problem by creating a computed property in VueJs to filter and return the value, but I really want to understand why the promise or the async approach does not work

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your dates equality check fails, you shouldn't compare dates like in your filter function, you should parse them to `Date` object first and then compare them using their `getTime` method, like this:

`date1.getTime() === date2.getTime()`

Comment: I have tested the filter manually triggering it after the data has been received, so the filter works when triggered manually with the same data.

Comment: Okay, just keep in mind that your check is error prone :)

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up will fix that one also :)